# Yii2 gridview filter by using autocomplete textbox

Tags: gridview, yii2

Before I have used comboBox instead of default(textBox) for searching in the gridview by using this one:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'project_status', 
    'filter' => $someArray,
    'value' => 'projectstatus.name',
]
```

But I want to change from comboBox to autocomplete textBox so the search function is still working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually set an AutoComplete widget as the filter. The following code works for me:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'project_status',
    'filter' => AutoComplete::widget([
        'model' => $filterModel,
        'attribute' => 'project_status',
        'clientOptions' => [
            'source' => ['USA', 'RUS'],
        ],
    ]),
    'value' => 'projectstatus.name'
]
```

Although you may have to tweak it a little for proper search to happen upon selecting a value.

Comment: also need to add the autocomplete library, php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui source here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui